# introduced eslint husky lint-staged, how to scan only the changed files when git commit

Tags: eslint-config-vue

After the old project introduced `eslint husky lint-staged`, executing `git commit` will scan the whole, one is too slow, and the other old code does not dare to change easily, thinking about only detecting the files changed by `commit` this time , how to configure

Answer (score 0):

configure `eslint --cache --fix`